# Interaction syntax in Stata

Tags: stata

My question concerns the proper use of `#` versus `##` in Stata for interacting categorical and dependent variables. Here is the example I have in mind.

To understand the marginal effect of *x* on *y* I ran an experiment with three treatments (*A, B, C)* on two types of subjects (*M, F*). To understand the pooled marginal effect (and supposing I satisfy all OLS criteria) I can run `reg y x`. However I also want to understand the marginal effect for each "species" in each "environment", or the interactions of *x* with treatment and types.

Firstly, assuming *x* is continuous, is the proper syntax for estimating the pooled marginal effect *and* the treatment-type marginal effect

```
reg y x i.treatment#i.type#c.x
```

or

```
reg y i.treatment#i.type##c.x
```

or neither?

Secondly, is the proper syntax for estimating just the treatment-type marginal effect

```
reg y i.treatment#i.type#c.x, noconstant
```

wherein the constant is dropped? If the constant is kept, does it represent the pooled response?

Sorry if this is a rudimentary question, but after a few days reading I still struggle to grasp exactly what is the difference between `#` and `##`.  Many thanks in advance.

Note: the data proposed are clearly a panel so the `xtreg` command is more appropriate. To keep things simple I just pretended the data were simpler.

**Edit**: Here is an example with a built-in Stata dataset.

```
    . reg price c.mpg##i.foreign

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  3,    70) =    9.48
       Model |   183435281     3  61145093.6           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |   451630115    70  6451858.79           R-squared     =  0.2888
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.2584
       Total |   635065396    73  8699525.97           Root MSE      =  2540.1

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          mpg |  -329.2551   74.98545    -4.39   0.000    -478.8088   -179.7013
    1.foreign |  -13.58741   2634.664    -0.01   0.996    -5268.258    5241.084
              |
foreign#c.mpg |
           1  |   78.88826   112.4812     0.70   0.485    -145.4485     303.225
              |
        _cons |   12600.54   1527.888     8.25   0.000     9553.261    15647.81
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`mpg` and `1.foreign` capture, respectively, the marginal effect of a car's miles per gallon and whether it is foreign or domestic on price. `foreign#c.mpg` captures the interaction between the category dummy and the continuous *x* when the dummy is one (ie the car is foreign)? What then captures the interaction of domestic (dummy is zero) with `mpg`?

Answer (score 2):

### 1.

In the following you are including the main effect of `x` and a three-way interaction.

```
reg y x i.treatment#i.type#c.x
```

You are leaving out main effects, specifically, that of `treatment` and `type`.

The following

```
reg y i.treatment#i.type##c.x
```

expands to

```
reg y i.treatment#i.type c.x i.treatment#i.type#c.x
```

which includes the main effect of `x`, a two-way interaction and a three-way interaction.

Look around for information on the inclusion of interactions with(out) main effects. For example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11009/including-the-interaction-but-not-the-main-effects-in-a-model.

### 2.

You say

> I still struggle to grasp exactly what is the difference between # and ##.

This can be clarified reading `help fvvarlist` and the manual. At this stage, what the syntax implies doesn't seem to be the problem, but rather how to specify the model, which will depend on what theory suggests, what has been done before, etc.

### 3.

From your example

```
reg price c.mpg##i.foreign
```

which expands to

```
reg price c.mpg i.foreign c.mpg#i.foreign
```

(the two main effects of `mpg` and `foreign`, and the interaction between them), you ask

> `foreign#c.mpg` captures the interaction between the category dummy and the continuous x when the dummy is one (ie the car is foreign)? What then captures the interaction of domestic (dummy is zero) with mpg?

Writing out the model helps (again two main effects and the intercation):

```
price = 12600.54 - 329.2551 mpg - 13.58741 foreign + 78.88826 mpg foreign
```

This clearly states how the effect of `mpg` over price is affected by the value of `foreign`; and how the effect of `foreign` over `price` is affected by the value of `mpg`. Because `foreign` takes only the values `0` and `1`, the effect of `mpg` over `price` is easier to understand. Just substitute out `foreign` in

```
- 329.2551 mpg + 78.88826 mpg foreign
```

When `foreign == 1`, the effect of `mpg` is `-250.36684`. When `foreign == 0`, the effect is `-329.2551`.

The effect of `foreign` over `price` is computed likewise:

```
- 13.58741 foreign + 78.88826 mpg foreign
```

but now substituting out `mpg`. Because it is continuous, you should probably plug-in several values of `mpg` to better understand its effect over `price` (see `help margins`.)

(That's all assuming the corresponding coefficients are statiscally significant.)

I sense your question involves trouble in understanding both Stata syntax and statistical issues. The first can be clarified reading Stata help resources. Regarding the second, your question is phrased in such a way that people at Cross-Validated discarded it as a programming problem.

Comment: Roberto is correct, as usual. There is much too much Stata here for Cross Validated and rather too much statistics for Stack Overflow. That doesn't pose an insoluble dilemma as Roberto has posted material that should help and Statalist is a third alternative.

Comment: Thanks Roberto. Then is Statalist a better outlet for this question? Or was it downvoted for some other reason.

Comment: I didn't downvote this; those who downvoted didn't reveal themselves or explain. That is common, as some people react irritably at downvoters. But the criteria for downvoting are "does not show any research effort" and "is unclear or not useful". My impression is that lack of a very specific problem based on very specific code pulls you down and it being unlikely that a question would benefit others much are high in many people's minds when they downvote; that's true for me when I have downvoted on other questions.